# can a constant pointer be changed during for iterations?

Tags: constants

I've just started learning C++ with openCV and came across a weird thing, for me at least...
in this code, there's a for loop, in which there is an assignment to a "const uchar*" as a function of the index (j).

```
for(int j = 1; j < myImage.rows - 1; ++j)
{
    const uchar* previous = myImage.ptr<uchar>(j - 1);
    const uchar* current  = myImage.ptr<uchar>(j    );
    const uchar* next     = myImage.ptr<uchar>(j + 1);

    uchar* output = Result.ptr<uchar>(j);

    for(int i = nChannels; i < nChannels * (myImage.cols - 1); ++i)
    {
        *output++ = saturate_cast<uchar>(5 * current[i]
                     -current[i - nChannels] - current[i + nChannels] - previous[i] - next[i]);
    }
}
```

As far as I know, constants can only be assigned once, during the construction, so what is going on in here?

I think I am missing a big part of the algorithm, and wish to understand its nature.

Please don't refer to the implementation itself for it is known to be non effective whatsoever. Also it's my first question posted to StackOverflow, so please consider ;)

Comment: The `const` variables are within the scope of the loop. They are created afresh each time the loop iterates and destroyed each time the loop's closing curly brace is hit. So they are not overwritten each time, they are created from new.

Comment: cheers @AndyBrown
So what is the purpose of using const for this example?
why not using an uchar* and overwrite it each iteration?